# do method addresses get moved around by the garbage collector?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, managed, unsafe

I know the GC can/will move stuff around on the heap. But if you get a pointer to a method, would you ever risk that method being moved?

Second. If you have a pointer to a method is there an unsafe/quick way to invoke it?

Comment: C# doesn't have pointers.You have references to objects (or delegates) and you'll never have to worry about them moving. If they do, you'll never know it.

Comment: The garbage collector will compact the heap.  However, when it compacts the heap, it handles updating of memory addresses.

Comment: @Steve ... C# does have pointers to be accurate [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)

Comment: @Steve: I assure you that C# has pointers. Read chapter 18 of the specification!

Comment: I stand corrected. More to read, apparently. @Eric, from your answer, it seems like there's little need to have to know about these for the most part, though.

Comment: @Steve: C# has been designed so that 99.999% of the time you don't need to use pointers. Its there for interoperability with unmanaged code, and for the very few situations in which you need the raw speed of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if you get a pointer to a method, would you ever risk that method being moved?

How are you planning on getting the pointer to the method?  C# doesn't have such an operation!

Suppose for the sake of argument that you did. The answer to your question is no, methods aren't moved by the GC. *Methods aren't deleted*, so why would they be *moved*? You move something in order to compact the hole left behind by a deletion.

But you don't get a pointer to a method in the first place in C#. You get a delegate.

There are ways to get a raw pointer with marshaling code, but what's the point? You can't invoke it.

> If you have a pointer to a method is there an unsafe/quick way to invoke it?

But you *don't* have a pointer to a method in C#, so again, the question is nonsensical.

You invoke a delegate by, well, invoking a delegate.

Now, again, if you somehow managed to get a pointer to a method in C#, is there a way to invoke it that is faster and lighter weight than making a delegate and then invoking that?

No. There is no way in C# to cause the compiler to generate a `calli` instruction, which is what you need.

The feature is *possible*; I once played around with a prototype of the features you want. When last I saw the priority list it was very, very low on that list so I would not expect it soon.

Comment: Exactly the information I was interested in. Thanks! .ps. Could F# or Reflection.Emit do anything similar?

Comment: @AustinHarris: if you want to use Reflection.Emit to generate a calli instruction you go right ahead and do that, but I would suggest to you that doing so is probably more work than just making a delegate. You should ask your F# question to an F# expert. If only there were a web site full of programming experts...

Comment: Methods can sometimes be deleted by the GC: You need a [collectible assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932(v=vs.110).aspx) which, once there are no more references to it, can be collection. This includes removing the contained methods and their JITted code. This might also affect instantiations of generic methods which are defined in a normal assembly but use a type from a collectible assembly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Good point, though even in collectible assemblies I would be very surprised if methods moved.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question only makes sense in the context of interop with unmanaged code. For example:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

protected int CbtHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    return Win32.CallNextHookEx(this.cbtHookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// ...
// keep the delegate reference, avoid "a callback was made on a garbage collected delegate" runtime error
this.cbtHookProc = new Win32.HookProc(CbtHookProc); 

// install the hook
this.cbtHookId = Win32.SetWindowsHookEx(Win32.WH_CBT, this.cbtHookProc,
    IntPtr.Zero, Win32.GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Note how a thunk for `CbtHookProc` is created and passed to `SetWindowsHookEx`. The piece of memory allocated for the think object is fixed for the life-time of `this.cbtHookProc`, it won't be moved around during heap compaction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as calling unmanaged function pointers, you can call them via:

- [the (semi)pure .net way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx)

Use one or both, depending on your needs.

Be sure to correctly set the calling convention, and make sure that you correctly setup the expected environment context for control flow into the function (ie: some functions expect to be invoked on the UI thread, for example, it all depends on the function you are calling into)